# Tensorflow Serving: get_model_status is missing the 'utils'

Tags: python, status, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to use some (presumably) standard features of tensorflow serving, but I am running into an odd problem. I am trying to implement some simple health-check for served models following https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/setup.

I did this by first creating a simple Docker image with Ubuntu 18.04 (also tried for 16.04) and then installing python3-dev (python3.6 as of this writing), before downloading and installing the necessary packages including gRPC as given above. As I am not interested in building it from source, I skipped Bazel. 
Doing:

`pip3 install tensorflow-serving-api`

installs the tensorflow-serving-api (1.9.0 as of this writing) without a problem, but when I try to:

`from tensorflow_serving.apis import get_model_status_pb2`

to utilize the model status, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_serving/apis/get_model_status_pb2.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow_serving.util import status_pb2 as tensorflow__serving_dot_util_dot_status__pb2
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow_serving.util'
```

Looking at `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_serving` there is no `util` directory. Is anyone else experiencing this when just using pip to install tensorflow_serving and know of a fix to this? If I do build tensorflow serving from source I get the directory, so I suppose a fix to make a wheel out of this, but I am curious nevertheless.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/pull/999), and should be out with the next release of the API.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, download the wheel https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-serving-api/#files from the given link. You either extract it using `7-zip` extractor and use it as a source folder for imports or install the `.whl` file using `pip`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the above link - when opened as a compressed archive - does not contain the utils folder either.

Comment: Hi, this issue was present in tensorflow serving. They have recently fixed it. Please find the fix at https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/pull/999 . Just clone the current master branch and try running. It should work.